# Vanishing of $r$-fold cup-products

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, homology-cohomology

In my notes there is the following result:

> Suppose $X$ can be covered by $r$-many open and path-connected sets $X=X_1\cup\ldots \cup X_r$. Assume that $H^\ast(X_i)=0$ for all $i=1,\ldots, r$. Then for any $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r\in H^{\ast\geq 1}(X)$, we have $\alpha_1\cup\ldots\cup\alpha_r=0$.

First question: *When they write $H^\ast(X_i)=0$ they mean that the reduced cohomology $\tilde{H}^\ast(X_i)=0$ vanishes, correct? Otherwise this result would be boring, as then $X_i=\emptyset$, i.e. $X=\emptyset$. In other words, the condition is equivalent to the fact that $X$ can be covered by $r$-many contractible open sets, right?*

Second question:  *What are some noteable applications of this result? Any cohomology rings that can be easily calculated using this proposition?*

Comment: 1) yes, probably. Though I’m not sure that $H^{\ast \geq 1}(X_i)=0$ (for a path-connected $X_i$) implies that $X_i$ is contractible. 2) I don’t know. It’s possible that there isn’t any striking application of this result, that it’s more about showing “what we can do” in such a setting.

Comment: 2: From your quoted result it follows that the cup product on the cohomology ring of a (free) suspension is trivial in positive degrees. To see this, note that the free suspension $SX$ of a space $X$ is (homeomorphic to) the union of two cones of $X$, which are contractible.

Comment: So you are saying that an unreduced suspension has Lusternik-Schnirlemann category at most $2$ and therefore cup length at most $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the cup product defines a map $$H^*(X,A) \times H^*(X,B) \longmapsto H^*(X,A\cup B).$$ If $U$ is a set in your cover (you need only assume that the inclusion $U\to X$ is nullhomotopic, not that $U$ is itself contractible), then $H^*(X,U)\to H^*(X)$ is onto (look at the long exact sequence), so that whenever you pick $r$ different cocycles, you can assume they come from relative cohomology, and then their product maps to $H^*(X,X)$, the zero group.

This fact relates the [*cup length*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology_ring#:%7E:text=A%20numerical%20invariant%20derived%20from,equal%20to%20its%20complex%20dimension.) of a space to its [Lusternik–Schnirlemann category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusternik%E2%80%93Schnirelmann_category), namely it gives that $\mathrm{cl}(X) \leqslant \mathrm{cat}(X)$.

For example, you can cover $\mathbb CP^n$ by $n+1$ affine subsets, but not $n$, because the degree $2$ generator $\xi$ satisfies $\xi^n\neq 0$, so the cup length is at least $n+1$, and so $\mathrm{cat}(\mathbb CP^n) = n+1$.

Comment: Shouldn't it say that the cup length of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is $n$? At least if you follow wikipedia, which defines the cup length as the "maximum number of graded elements of degree greater or equal to $1$ that when multiplied give a non-zero result."

Comment: Similarly, shouldn't it be $\mathrm{cl}(X) < \mathrm{cat}(X)$?

Comment: @Peter It seems to be a matter of definitions. I define the LS cat to be the least integer $c$ such that $X$ can be covered with $c$ subsets whose inclusions are null-homotopic. In the case of projective $n$-space, you need at most $n+1$, since you have an affine cover by that many affine subsets. The cup length is the least $\ell$ such that any $\ell$ elements of positive degree have zero product.