# Cohomology determining homotopy type

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a path-connected topological space such that its reduced cohomology vanishes, i.e. $\tilde{H}^i(X)=0$. Does it follow that $X$ is contractible (i.e homotopy equivalent to a point)?

(This question was motivated by [this question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4777089/vanishing-of-r-fold-cup-products).)

Comment: Duplicate, if not related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29957/do-trivial-homology-groups-imply-contractibility-of-a-compact-polyhedron

Comment: @JonasLinssen This question is about cohomology.

Comment: Does not matter, it is the same example.

Comment: To get from homology vanishing to cohomology vanishing, use the universal coefficients theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. For simply connected spaces, examples that fail would not be CW complexes (e.g. the Warsaw Circle). Within CW complexes, there are examples $X$ with $\pi_1(X)$ non-trivial (so not contractible) with reduced integral (co)homology vanishing. See the link in the comment above to avoid duplicative answers.